# rxtx giving me NoSuchPortException

Tags: java, windows, serial-port, rxtx

I am not a Java programmer and I am trying to configure a gsm modem for sms. The software requires the use of RXTX. I have a windows 7 machine 32 bit. I have installed the rxtx files in the correct java path. I have placed RXTXcomm.jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext. I have also put the file rxtxSerial.dll in the following path.. C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin. The software i am trying to configure with gsm modem is an open source software called Cyclos.  The software requires that I set the com port and baud rate in a properties file. I have done that and double checked it. I have even connected via putty to the com port that the modem is connected to. I verified it by issuing a ATZ ( Hayes reset command ) and received an "ok" response.  I have searched their forum for assistance with no luck. Can someone point my in the right direction as to how to resolve this issue?

Below is my error log.

```
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO PropertiesFactoryBean - Loading properties file from class path resource [modemDriverConfig.properties]
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO DriverEngine - =========================================================================================================================================================
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO DriverEngine - ====================== SMS Driver. Released on Fri, 21 Dec 2012 14:23:36 +0300 with version number 1.2. Id: aioDriver. VM Time zone: Eastern African Time
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO DriverEngine - =========================================================================================================================================================
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO DriverEngine - Marking not delivered as failed messages...
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - Version: 3.5.1
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - JRE Version: 1.7.0
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - JRE Impl Version: 21.0-b17
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - O/S: Windows 7 / x86 / 6.1
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Initialized.
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager running...
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - Queue directory not defined. Queued messages will not be saved to filesystem.
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Initialized.
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - DelayQueueManager running...
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Initialized.
2013-10-23 19:41:12 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Starting gateway, using Huawei (Generic) AT Handler.
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Opening: /dev/COM7 @9600
2013-10-23 19:41:12  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Closing: /dev/COM7 @9600
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager end...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - DelayQueueManager end...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - Stopped.
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Stopping gateway...
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Closing: /dev/COM7 @9600
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO smslib - GTW: aioDriver: Gateway stopped.
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager end...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager end...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - Running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - NotifyQueueManager running...
2013-10-23 19:41:13 DEBUG smslib - Stopped.
2013-10-23 19:41:13 ERROR ModemDriverEngine - Error starting up the sms service
org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:102)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:276)
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11d2698: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,cxf.config0,securityProperties,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,cipherHelper,logUtils,unmarshaller,configResource,controllerConfig,facade,controllerServiceLocalLocator,driverServiceLocator,cyclosWsManager,driversWsManager,langManager,sessionHandler,removeExiredSessionsScheduler,messageSource,errorCodeVerifier,help,helpErrorHandler,infoText,infoTextErrorHandler,registration,registrationErrorHandler,performPayment,performPaymentErrorHandler,requestPayment,requestPaymentErrorHandler,accountDetails,accountDetailsErrorHandler,confirm,confirmErrorHandler,messageErrorHandler,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,controllerDaoOperation,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,controllerQuerydslConfiguration,messageLogDao,sessionDao,controlSessionDao,cyclosInstanceValidationInterceptor,driverInstanceValidationInterceptor,smsSenderWebServiceImpl,smsSenderWebService,controllerServiceImpl,controller,paymentRequestRxImpl,paymentRequestRx,baseProperties,driverServiceImpl,authInterceptor,driver,driverServiceLocalLocator,controllerServiceLocator,engine,smsDigestCleanerTask,messageFilter,toControllerMessageDispatcher,phoneNumberHelper,smsReceiverExecutor,taskScheduler,driverDaoOperation,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#1,driverQuerydslConfiguration,messageDao,smsDigestDao,txManager,querydslTemplates,txAdvice,dataSource,__dwrConfiguration,__monitorDwrService,monitorDwrService,smsProperties,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#1,monitorProperties,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#2,accessControlManager]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'smsReceiverExecutor'
2013-10-23 19:41:13  INFO ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2013-10-23 19:41:13 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facade' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driversWsManager' while setting bean property 'driversWsManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driversWsManager' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceLocator' while setting bean property 'driverServiceLocator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocalLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'driverWebService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'engine' while setting bean property 'driverEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driversWsManager' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceLocator' while setting bean property 'driverServiceLocator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocalLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'driverWebService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'engine' while setting bean property 'driverEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/controller/spring/core.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocalLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'driverWebService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'engine' while setting bean property 'driverEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceLocalLocator' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'driverServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'driverWebService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'engine' while setting bean property 'driverEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1102)
    at nl.strohalm.cyclos.driver.DriverServiceLocatorImpl.setApplicationContext(DriverServiceLocatorImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'engine' while setting bean property 'driverEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [nl/strohalm/cyclos/driver/spring/driverCore.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error starting up the sms service; nested exception is org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at nl.strohalm.cyclos.driver.modem.engine.ModemDriverEngine.doStartUp(ModemDriverEngine.java:114)
    at nl.strohalm.cyclos.driver.engine.DriverEngine.startUp(DriverEngine.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:102)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:276)
```

Comment: The com port doesn't exist? You seem to be trying to connect to `com7`.  Have you verified that the hardware is in fact on `com7`?

Comment: Yes I did verify it. I even used putty on com 7 and got a response from the modem.

Comment: Maybe rxtx native library doesn't know how to address com7. Can you set it up as com1, 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: I will give that a try and see what happens... will let u know...  thanks

Comment: I have finally got it to work.. problem was how i was defining the com port in the config file. I was originally defining the com port as =/dev/com4 but it should have simple been =com4. The documentation was not exactly clear that is why i had all this confusion. Thanks for all of you how tried to help..

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got it to work.. problem was how i was defining the com port in the config file. I was originally defining the com port as =/dev/com4 but it should have simple been =com4. The documentation was not exactly clear that is why i had all this confusion. Thanks for all of you how tried to help..

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users you can use the device manager to confirm the right port[image]